# typescript change type to Partial(not undefined so it wont trigger error 2741) base on value type

Tags: typescript

```
type A = {
a:number
b:boolean
}

type C<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends boolean ? <?????> : T[K] }

type D = C<A> // {a:number, b?:boolean}
```

I want to convert `boolean` to `partial boolean`, what I suppose to fill in `<????>`

Note, `boolean | undefined` is not acceptable because

[image]

To make it clear, I need **`Partial` itself**, not `undefined`

Comment: `boolean | undefined`

Comment: this wont work, as it warn property b is missing if I use that type

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24951

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post answer here so I can mark this question as answered

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24951